C# Timer triggering before the interval ends
I am using System.Timers.Timer in C# to schedule a task that needs to be performed every 5 seconds. However, I have noticed that the Timer sometimes triggers before the interval ends. Here is my code:
internal class IcbDataProcessor : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<IcbDataProcessor> _logger;
    private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private readonly TimeSpan _interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    public IcbDataProcessor(ILogger<IcbDataProcessor> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(_interval);
        _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var nextTime = RoundUp(now, _interval);
        if (nextTime > now)
        {
            await Task.Delay(nextTime - now, stoppingToken);
        }
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private static DateTime? _prevRoundedTime;
    private void Timer_Elapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var roundedTime = RoundDown(DateTime.Now, _interval);
            if (roundedTime == _prevRoundedTime)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("IcbDataProcessor: Prev Rounded Time is equals to Rounded Time: {Time}", roundedTime);
            }

            //To do
            _prevRoundedTime = roundedTime;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "DataProcessor EXCEPTION {Message}", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public static DateTime RoundUp(DateTime date, TimeSpan d)
    {
        return new DateTime((date.Ticks + d.Ticks - 1) / d.Ticks * d.Ticks, date.Kind);
    }

    public static DateTime RoundDown(DateTime date, TimeSpan d)
    {
        return new DateTime(date.Ticks / d.Ticks * d.Ticks, date.Kind);
    }
}

When I examine the stored time, I see that there are instances when the Timer starts as follows: 10:10:25.001, 10:10:29.999. Clearly, the interval between the previous and the next instance is not yet 5 seconds, leading to my roundedTime being rounded to the same number. I have checked and am sure that my event completes very quickly (about 20ms) and there are no errors in my code.
Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

if d.Ticks is an integer, you have integer division ....

Also: What order of precision are you expecting? Afaik it's about 17-ish ms if I remember correctly. At least in the low 2-digits even on a recent system.

"Clearly, the interval between the previous and the next instance is not yet 5 seconds" - I would not be so sure that this is that clear (see previous comments). Also I would recommend to dive a bit into the docs - "Because the Timer class depends on the system clock, it has the same resolution as the system clock. When run on a Windows system whose system clock has a resolution of approximately 15 milliseconds".

Timer might not be precise enough for your needs. What are you trying to do that requires such exact timing?

Please look at the RoundUp and RoundDown methods, 10:10:25.001 will round down to 10:10:25, 10:10:29.999 will also round down to 10:10:25. I don’t need absolute exact timing, but I need the timer not to trigger less than the interval, and not more than twice the interval, for the RoundDown function to work correctly.

I'll be real with you, if a difference in the fourth decimal of a timer interval isn't good enough for you, then your algorithm is absolutely atrocious and definitely not fit for a protected mode system like Windows. Simply write a better algorithm. Failing that, use a real-time OS like QNX or Arduino or something.

Assuming you used DateTime.Now to examine time as in the code, let's take a look at an example of time passing, like this:



Event
Time
Interval
Elapsed




Timer_Elapsed is fired
10:10:24.986

0


After some CPU cyclesGet DateTime.Now
10:10:25.001
i₀
0+i₀


Timer_Elapsed is fired
10:10:29.996

5.01


After some CPU cyclesGet DateTime.Now
10:10:29.999
i₁
5.01+i₁



The interval between the 2 examiations is 5.01 - (i₀ - i₁). If the value of i suddenly increases during the firing of an event, it will cause a deviation in your calculated interval.
The solution depends on what you want to do.

If you just want to execute a method every N seconds, then you assume that the timer always runs correctly at the set interval.

If you want to execute a method N times within a certain period of time, you can record the number of executions. If the number of executions is not enough after the specified time, you can add an extra one (just like in leap seconds).

Round to the closest time:
public static DateTime Round(DateTime date, TimeSpan d)
{
    var t = d.Ticks;
    var dt = date.Ticks;
    var rt = dt / t * t;
    if(dt - rt >= t / 2)
        rt += t;
    return new DateTime(rt, date.Kind);
}




Please look at the RoundUp and RoundDown methods, 10:10:25.001 will round down to 10:10:25, 10:10:29.999 will also round down to 10:10:25. I don’t need absolute exact timing, but I need the timer not to trigger less than the interval, and not more than twice the interval, for the RoundDown function to work correctly.

The time you get is not the time the event fires, and you cannot accurately get this time, so you can only trust the interval of the timer. You cannot round down, but you can round it to the nearest time.
